# How do I reduce lines of code in this piece of code? A number of lines are being repeated in updateProfileFlags and fetchProfileObj

Tags: java

This method initiates a new connection with the thrift client and returns a profile object

```
 private TResume fetchProfileObj(int userId) {
    try{
        TTransport transport = new TSocket("172.XX.X.XXX”, 9311);  
        transport.open();
        TProtocol protocol = new  TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        Map<String, String> ids = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ids.put("requestId", "settingsService");
        TResumeService.Client resumeServiceClient = new TResumeService.Client(protocol);
        TResume profileObj = resumeServiceClient.getFullActiveProfileFromUserId(ids, 105, userId, "resman5_1");
        transport.close();
        return profileObj;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This method updates the profile object recieved from the fetchProfile method

```
private void updateProfileFlags(TResume profile,int recruiterJobAlert) {
    try{
        TTransport transport = new TSocket("172.XX.X.XXX", 9321);  
        transport.open();
        TProtocol protocol = new  TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        Map<String, String> ids = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ids.put("requestId", "settingsService");
        TUpdateResume.Client updateResumeClient = new TUpdateResume.Client(protocol);
        profile.getUser().setResdexVisibility(recruiterJobAlert>0?"a":"c");
        updateResumeClient.saveProfile(ids, 105, profile.getProfile(), "now", "resman5_1", null);
        transport.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now calling the above methods

```
public void myTestMethod(){
updateProfileFlags(fetchProfileObj(userId),settings.getRecruiterJobAlert());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Extract the duplicated map into a constant field (that'll remove 2 lines from both method) :

```
private static final Map<String, String> IDS = Collections.singletonMap("requestId", "settingsService");
```

2) Extract the creation of the `TResumeService.Client` and `TUpdateResume.Client` in separate methods looking like this :

```
private TResumeService.Client createService(TTransport transport) {
    return new TResumeService.Client(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
}
```

3) Do not close your `TTransport` in the try block, indeed if an exception is thrown it'll never be closed, use the finally block for this.

4) Do not catch Exception to simply use `printStackTrace`, it's bad practice as the calling method won't know if (nor how) the method failed. If the methods cannot manage the exception... they should rethrow it. If having a general `Exception` object being thrown around does not suit you, you may wrap it inside an IOException for example like this :

```
try{
    TTransport transport = new TSocket("172.XX.X.XXX”, 9311);  
    transport.open();
    // ....
    return profileObj;
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new IOException(e);
}
```

5) Use a whitespace after commas and add some space in the following expression `(recruiterJobAlert>0?"a":"c"` to make it more readable

6) Put the string and 105 and 9311 "magic" values in properly named constants.

7) It's useless to store something in a variable and then simply return it, you should consider removing such assigment.

At this point, you'll have the following code :

```
private static final String RESMAN = "resman5_1";

private static final Map<String, String> IDS = Collections.singletonMap("requestId", "settingsService");

private TResumeService.Client createResumeService(TTransport transport) {
    return new TResumeService.Client(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
}

private TUpdateResume.Client createUpdateService(TTransport transport) {
    return new TUpdateResume.Client(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
}

private TResume fetchProfileObj(int userId) throws IOException {
    try{
        TTransport transport = new TSocket("172.XX.X.XXX”, PORT);  
        transport.open();
        TResumeService.Client resumeServiceClient = createResumeService(transport);
        return resumeServiceClient.getFullActiveProfileFromUserId(IDS, SOME_CONSTANT, userId, RESMAN);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } finally {
        transport.close();
    }
}

private void updateProfileFlags(TResume profile, int recruiterJobAlert) throws IOException {
    try{
        TTransport transport = new TSocket("172.XX.X.XXX", PORT);  
        transport.open();
        TUpdateResume.Client updateResumeClient = createUpdateService(transport);
        profile.getUser().setResdexVisibility(recruiterJobAlert > 0 ? "a" : "c");
        updateResumeClient.saveProfile(IDS, SOME_CONSTANT, profile.getProfile(), "now", RESMAN, null);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } finally {
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

---

Maybe you'll find that's enough of an improvement but there is still 6-7 lines duplicated between the 2 methods.
Let's dig a bit more and go functionnal :

We can see that the 2 methods look like this :

```
try{
    TTransport transport = new TSocket("172.XX.X.XXX”, PORT);  
    transport.open();
    // something that varies here
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new IOException(e);
} finally {
    transport.close();
}
```

The `something that varies` could be abstracted with a function...
Since Java 8 we can pass objects that are very tiny wrappers around functions, they are called `lambda`s.
Let's take a look at the package storing all those objects : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html
We sadly cannot use `Function` as it cannot throw exception... there is a `Callable` interface in java.util.concurrent but we cannot use it as it doesn't take any parameter... so let's use a new functional interface that suits our needs :

```
public interface ApplicationOverTransport<R> {
    R call(TTransport transport) throws Exception;
}
```

This interface would simply replace the variable part, we can now create a simple method that will be usable everytime you need a TTransport that is opened, do some actions and closed :

```
T applyOverTransport(ApplicationOverTransport<T> method) throws IOException {
    try{
        TTransport transport = new TSocket("172.XX.X.XXX”, PORT);  
        transport.open();
        return method.call(transport);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } finally {
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

By using lambda expressions, the methods could then look like this :

```
private TResume fetchProfileObj(int userId) throws IOException {
    return applyOverTransport(transport -> {
        TResumeService.Client resumeServiceClient = createService(transport);
        return resumeServiceClient.getFullActiveProfileFromUserId(IDS, SOME_CONSTANT, userId, RESMAN);
    });
}

private void updateProfileFlags(TResume profile, int recruiterJobAlert) throws IOException {
    applyOverTransport(transport -> {
        TUpdateResume.Client updateResumeClient = createService(transport);
        profile.getUser().setResdexVisibility(recruiterJobAlert > 0 ? "a" : "c");
        updateResumeClient.saveProfile(IDS, SOME_CONSTANT, profile.getProfile(), "now", RESMAN, null);
        return null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how many lines of code can be reduced but one thing is for sure: whenever you encounter a resource that can be closed, you should use Java try-with-resources feature (since java 7).  Not only this feature saves you the `close()` operation (one line less!) but also ensures that the resource is properly closed by the end of the try block no matter if it ended successfully or not (the compiler adds a `finally` clause). in the current code, if an exception is thrown, the `Ttransport` resource is not closed properly.

I looked at the [thrift javadoc](http://atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.thrift/libthrift/0.10.0/org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport.html) and indeed from version 0.10.0, `Ttransport` is auto-closeable.  So the code on both methods should be

```
try (TTransport transport = new TSocket("172.XX.X.XXX", 9321)) {
  transport.open();
  ...  // do not call close()!!
  // do not call close()!! it is added by the compiler
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Regarding reducing duplicated lines, I can offer that you make a method to create the `ids` map.  so if the contents of the map need to be modified due to modifications in the requirements or API, there will be only one place to modify them.  creating constant variables instead of embedded literals is also considered best practice.  This can apply to other literals used in the code

```
public static final String PROFILE_REQUEST_KEY = "requestId";
public static final String PROFILE_REQUEST_VALUE = "settingsService";
public static final int    PROFILE_WHATEVER_105_MEANS = 105;
public static final String PROFILE_WHATEVER_RESMAN5_1_MEANS = "resman5_1";

public Map<String, String> getProfileRequestProperties() {
  return Collections.singletonMap(PROFILE_REQUEST_KEY, PROFILE_REQUEST_VALUE);
}
```

now, since we eliminated `close()`, we can return the value direct from the call to the client, eliminating the creation of the `profileObj` reference:

```
return resumeServiceClient.getFullActiveProfileFromUserId(
         getProfileRequestProperties(),
         PROFILE_WHATEVER_105_MEANS,
         userId,
         PROFILE_WHATEVER_RESMAN5_1_MEANS);
```

so, I ma not sure how many LOC are now present, but im my eyes, the code is clearer and more maintainable and extensible.